# Sorting is very slow in Spreadjs

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, wijmo

In Spreadjs grid from Wijmo, Sorting of data is very slow when it comes to thousands of rows.

Can anyone suggest any solution for the same?

Comment: can you sort the raw data yourself, before displaying it?

Comment: I want to use the in-built functionality for sort. So sorting the raw data and displaying does not meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Which build are you using ? There was an issue related to performance when sorting is performed and has been fixed in the latest version 8.40.20151.0. Here is the link for latest version: http://spread.grapecity.com/Products/SpreadJS

Comment: Hi Ashish, I am using the same version as mentioned by you above